# downloaded books from google play on wrong account on my nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7

i just downloaded some books via google play on my nexus 7 but under my daughters account, I don't want my credit card on her account how do i fix this but not loose the books?

Comment: Simply taking the credit card from the account is no option? (Admitted, I didn't try that yet; but I'm pretty sure it can be replaced, so it should be removable as well) What's already paid with it is paid, and the books will certainly remain on your daughter's account.